# Want to install FlightGear but 'libapr1' dependency cannot be satisfied

Tags: linux-mint, kde, package-management, apt, deb

When I want to install the `flightgear:amd64` package, it requests to install the `simgear2.8.0:amd64` package onto my Linux Mint 13 KDE 64-bit system. But I cannot install `simgear2.8.0:amd64` because I could not find it in the GetDeb repositories, could not install it from PlayDeb, and could not find a **.deb** file online. So, I tried to install `simgear2.8.0:i386`, but it wants me to install (read **reinstall**) `libapr1`, but it is already installed properly with its dependencies.

By the way, `libapr1` is necessary for my Apache installation. Could you help me fix my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this problem on the same day I posted this question. I just needed to add the `games` section to my GetDeb repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` through the Synaptic Package Manager.

P.S.: I know someone who says that Synaptic is unreliable, Muon is broken, and Mint Update is trash.

P.P.S.: I also know someone who does not recommend installing Microsoft Flight. I agree with him.

Happy flying! (Tux-related pun intended.)